# Angular - rewrite for ErrorDocument add old path to new path uri after redirect

Tags: angular, apache, mod-rewrite

### Summary

I have a weird interaction in my apache config when i try to trigger my **503** ErrorDocument, the first path is added to the second ui path after my RewriteRule does the redirect.

I have a lot of micro-services wrote in Angular 12, so to simplify and explain my problem i will simplify my conf with an example, one is an app that need to trigger the maintenance page and the other one is the maintenance app that use angular route parameters.

### Conf

Here is the apache httpd.conf for the two :

```
<Directory "/opt/apache/www/html/old-ui">
     <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
         RewriteEngine On
         ErrorDocument 503 /maintenance-ui/old
         RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maintenance.enable -f
         RewriteRule ^.*$ - [R=503]
         # RewriteRule ^.*$ /maintenance-ui/old [L,NC,R=503] # also tried that

         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
         RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d [OR]
         RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f

         RewriteRule ^ - [L]
         RewriteRule ^ \index.html
     </IfModule>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     AllowOverride All
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

```
<Directory "/opt/apache/www/html/maintenance-ui">
     <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
         RewriteEngine On
         RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d [OR]
         RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f

         RewriteRule ^ - [L]
        RewriteRule ^ index.html

     </IfModule>

     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     AllowOverride All
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: MaintenanceComponent },
  { path: ':nameService', component: MaintenanceComponent }
];
```

### Result

My problem is that when i enter https://my-web-site/old-ui/ in my browser instead of being redirected to :

- https://my-web-site/maintenance-ui/old

I end up with :

- https://my-web-site/maintenance-ui/old-ui (it's like apache added the old path as an uri)

And apache logs seems to say that i sent the right thing:

`[perdir /opt/apache/www/html/maintenance-ui/] strip per-dir prefix: /opt/apache/www/html/maintenance-ui/old-> old`

(log file) : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LFtAppgIsVCXmeB-Ku9hyTgIgWPeitHs/view?usp=sharing

So what's the problem here ?

***P.S :*** I need to use route parameter to dynamically change what I need to show to the user depending of what app they came from.

***P.S 2 :*** I could do a `.split('-')` in angular to remove the **-ui**, but i find it dirty when my conf apache seems ok.

Comment: Are you actually "redirected" to `/maintenance/old-ui`? The `R=503` is not a redirect as such, the 503 (a non 3xx status) is served via an internal subrequest. Do you have `.htaccess` files as well? You are explicitly enabling `.htaccess` overrides, but if you do have a `.htaccess` file then it will likely override these directives. You are also enabling `Indexes` and `MultiViews` - generally, these should both be _disabled_.

Comment: Yes, i am 'redirected' to `/maintenance/old-ui` (or more precisely i end up with a 200 status) after triggering `R=503` with my rewrite rules.
For `.htaccess` files, actually, i removed most of them in the past, the only one remaining is in `/opt/apache/www/html` and contain :
`Options -Indexes`
(I will test to remove these conf)

Comment: Ok, there's nothing in what you've posted that would trigger a 3xx external redirect. (Or result in `/maintenance/old-ui`.) If you are seeing a 200 OK status (no 3xx response) then this is triggered by client-side (JavaScript, meta refresh, ...) code. The request should be routed through `/maintenance-ui/index.html`.

Comment: yes it is `[perdir /opt/apache/www/html/maintenance-ui/] strip per-dir prefix: /opt/apache/www/html/maintenance-ui/old-> old` apache log it with my parameter.
But the strange thing is that the angular compiled resources seems fine (old referer pointing to https://my-web-site/old-ui and they have the right path `/opt/apache/www/html/maintenance-ui/runtime.c5220298cc1a479a03c1.js`). 
Finally it load my image in assets then the referer suddently change `pass through /opt/apache/www/html/maintenance-ui/assets/img/maintenance.png, referer: https://my-web-site/maintenance-ui/old-ui`

Comment: i added the log file in the description